# Including all files within a directory with Combres

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, combres

I'm using Combres to bundle a variety of JavaScript libraries, like that:

```
<resourceSet name="libraryScripts" type="js">
    <resource path="~/Scripts/Libraries/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" />
    <resource path="~/Scripts/Libraries/underscore-min.js" />
    <resource path="~/Scripts/Libraries/angular.min.js" />
    <!-- Omitted for brevity ... -->
</resourceSet>
```

Is there any way to specify an entire folder to include (here: *~/Scripts/Libraries/*) without having to list all JavaScript files explicitly, one by one?